# Visual Studio 2010 - UnitTest - Exception while using generics and AssemblyInitialize

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, generics

I have a problem with unit tests in Visual Studio 2010. I've pasted the simplified code below.

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClassA<T>
{
    [AssemblyInitialize()]
    public static void Initialize(TestContext testContext) {}
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClassB : TestClassA<String>
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
       Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When I run `TestMethod()`, I get the following exception:

```
Assembly Initialization method TestProject.TestClassA`1.Initialize threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.. Aborting test execution.

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.ThrowNoInvokeException()
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.RunAssemblyInitializeMethod()
```

When I google this bug, I can find advice how to fix code that uses reflection to call the [[AssemblyInitialize]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method. But that code is not mine, it's:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.RunAssemblyInitializeMethod()
```

I can use [[ClassInitialize]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245248%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method instead of [[AssemblyInitialize]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and it works, but still I would like to use [AssemblyInitialize] method.

Thank you in advance for any suggustions.

Comment: sorry, Visual Studio 2010, not 2008... I've just corrected it...

Comment: In your `Initialize` method, do you refer to type `T` at all?

Comment: No, I don't. It is not related, it just doesn't work together.

Comment: I tried without <T> and <string> . The test passes for me.

Comment: Well, thanks, but how is it supposed to help? My question was how to make it work all together - generics along with AssemlbyInitialize. Not to remove one part of it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually need the inheritance. You can put a separate class in your test project/assembly that contains both AssemblyInit and AssemblyCleanUp attributed methods.
Like so:

```
[TestClass]
public static class AssemblyInitializer
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
    {

    }

    [AssemblyCleanup]
    public static void AssemblyCleanup()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice workaround, thank you. Since I don't refer to type T in the initialize method, I don't need it present in that class, I can put it aside into some other class, like you suggested. The bug still remains there, but this workaround works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem still happen if you remove `[TestClass]` from `TestClassA<T>` ?

<strike>[TestClass]</strike>

```
 public class TestClassA<T>
 {
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I've already tried this one, but if I remove [TestClass] attribute, the [AssemblyInitialize] method will not get called at all.